# Listadapter show only last value of array in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview, android-studio

Guys i am working on an android project. I want to show 5 items in a list but i got only last item of array, basically this array come from a JSONarray. how can i solve this problem? this is my Main activity class

```
       try {
             Log.d("hy one ","two");
             //JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(data1);
             JSONArray jr=new JSONArray(data1);              
             for (int i=0;i<jr.length();i++) {
                 jsonObject = jr.getJSONObject(i);
                 like = jsonObject.getString(like_count);
            }
            JSONArray jsonArray3=jsonObject.getJSONArray("comments");
            HashMap<String, String> arr;
            for(int j=0;j<jsonArray3.length();j++){
            arr = new HashMap<>();
            JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(j);
            name11=jsonObject3.getString(name1);
            Log.d("name value",name11);

            arr.put("name",name11);
            arrayList.add(arr);
        }
        Log.d("arraylist", String.valueOf(arrayList));

  } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    /*list_adapter=new list_adapter(Dashboard.this);
    listcomment.setAdapter(listAdapter);*/
    adapter= new Dashboard_Adapter(Dashboard.this,arrayList);
   // Log.d("adapter", String.valueOf(adapter));

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

this is my adapter

```
public class Dashboard_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
   // ArrayList<String> arr;
    private Activity activity;
    public Context context;
    HashMap<String, String> arr;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;
    public Dashboard_Adapter(Context dashbord, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList) {
        activity = (Activity) dashbord;
      this.arrayList=arrayList;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        sharedPreferences = activity.getSharedPreferences(Login.My_Prefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
       // Log.d("arraysize",arrayList.size());

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.omments, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTags23);

            //comment
           // viewHolder.btnPromote = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFeedResponce);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        arr = new HashMap<>();
        arr = arrayList.get(position);

        viewHolder.Name.setText(Dashboard.name11);




        return view;
        // Glide.with(context).load(images).placeholder(R.drawable.home).into(imageView);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView Name;


    }

}
```

i think problem is in adapter.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked the arrayList size using a log before feeding it to the adapter on onPostExecute() ?

Comment: Move all parsing code inside `for (int i=0;i<jr.length();i++) {` loop.

Comment: yes i checked. all values are present in arraylist but not showing in final result

Comment: i moved all code inside the loop but still same problem

Comment: update you code here

Comment: sorry i did not understand, how update?

Comment: you are not parsing json properly...please post the complete json string in the question. Instead of this much complexity please use GSON or Jackson library for parsing the json

Answer (score 0):

```
 JsonObject jsonObject = New JsonObject();
```

inside for loop